# Change in buffer/cache use

Tags: memory

I am trying to see the change in buffer/cache used during a read operation.

```
free -m
truncate -s 10M /home/andy/Downloads/10_Mb_File.txt
cat 10_Mb_File.txt  > /dev/null; free -m

#andy@7 ~/Downloads> Create_10_Mb_File.sh
#total used free shared buff/cache available
#Mem: 6894 1414 2529 24 2951 5162
#Swap: 0 0 0
#total used free shared buff/cache available
#Mem: 6894 1414 2518 24 2961 5161
#Swap: 0 0 0
```

Why is there such a small small change during a 10 Mb read?

This does create a file with actual charcters. But no change in buffer/cache use.

```
 </dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c1000000 > /home/andy/Downloads/random.txt 
cat /home/andy/Downloads/random.txt > /dev/null; free -m
```

Comment: 2951 => 2961 is exactly 10MB as expected. The `available` value does not decrease (as you might expect) because cache can be immediately released, as it only duplicates what is also safe on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your operating system knows you're reading 0 bytes, which it doesn't need to buffer.

Or even read, because they were never written. All that happens during your `truncate` call, physically, is that the file system now contains a remark "there's 10 MB of zeros here.". That's the magic of sparse files!

Comment: Miller This does create a file with actual charcters. But no change in buffer/cache use. </dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c1000000 > /home/andy/Downloads/random.txt
cat /home/andy/Downloads/random.txt  > /dev/null; free -m

Comment: hm; maybe 10 MB is simply already reserved as cache space. Did you evict all caches before doing the measurement?

Comment: That is not so. Sure, `truncate -s 10M my10MB.txt` creates a sparse file which `du` says is zero blocks. But `cat` does not check sparseness: it gets back 10485760 real bytes. The OS does not even figure they are going to /dev/null: `cat` sends them through `write()`, and they still end up cached. Note the cache figure (in MB) goes from 2951 to 2961: that is your 10 MB increase. Just tried it with 1GB to exaggerate the effect.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant oh, I though `cat` would `splice`

Comment: @Marcus Müller  How do I evict all caches?

Comment: @MarcusMüller  `man splice` says "where one of the file descriptors must refer to a pipe".

Comment: @fixit7  Ah, we meet again.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant ah, sorry, meant `file_copy_ranges`; see `copy_cat(void)` in cat.c in GNU coreutils.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : man page for `copy_file_range` shows error case `EINVAL Either fd_in or fd_out is not a regular file`. I suspect `/dev/null` qualifies. I cannot find any useful references for `file_copy_range(s)` -- I suspect it was a git branch that died, or just a typo.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c#n507 a typo indeed, please ignore the trailing `s`

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Please re-read carefully. `cat` calls `copy_file_range()`. You say ".. meant `file_copy_ranges`": the words are in a different order. And `cat` immediately checks for `errno == EINVAL`, which is noted as sufficient grounds for rejection of that kernel call. `cat` may be smart enough to attempt to `splice` or `copy_file_range`, but not smart enough to deal with sparse files, or stat fd1 and discover it is /dev/null.

Comment: I am happy with the responses. I consider my question answered. @Paul_Pedant